# Using haskell classes internally in a function

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass

Imagine that there is some class:

```
class Foo a where
  g :: b -> a
  f :: a -> b
```

I want to be able to write the following function:

```
h :: a -> a
h = f . g
```

But to do this I need some way to specify the exact instance of Foo I'm using.  Is there some way to do this simillar to how Rust uses traits?  I'm pretty certain I could use template haskell to build this function with a supplied class each time, but if possible I'd like to about that.

Comment: But `h` has type `a -> a`.

Comment: Just fixed that, thanks

Comment: But are `b` the same type in `f` and `g`? They are not a part of the class signature, so they could be anything?

Comment: I dont really care what value b is. I need a way to specifify the value of the class used within h.  In this case h could be a -> b or a -> a.  I dont think that matters.

Comment: @pricks: well the problem is that - depending on the type of `b` - there can be several "correct" results for `h x` (with `x` a value). Since if `b ~ Int`, then we might attach a different meaning to it, than when it is a `Char`.

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between traits in Rust and typeclasses in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28123453/what-is-the-difference-between-traits-in-rust-and-typeclasses-in-haskell/29388580#29388580)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want `h` to decide internally which instance to use, just provide an annotation to remove the ambiguity. Say, if you want to choose `b ~ Int`

```
h :: Foo a => a -> a
h = f . (g :: Int -> a)
```

(I guess `Foo` will need another parameter `b` in your actual class, but in such case this approach can be adapted as needed).

If you instead need the *caller* of `h` to choose the instance, not `h` itself, you can use `AmbiguousTypes` and `TypeApplications` (and `ScopedTypeVariables`).

```
h :: forall b a . Foo a => a -> a
h = f . (g :: b -> a)
```

Later on, you can call `h` as in, e.g., `h @ Int` to choose `b ~ Int`.

Comment: How safe/unsafe are AmbiguaousTypes and TypeApplications?

Comment: @pricks They are perfectly safe, despite their scary name. The only price to pay for ambiguous types is that inference can not guess what `b` is since `b` does not occur in `h`'s type, so you will always need to use `h @ SomeType` in every call. These two extensions are usually used together.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly the solution a was looking for.

Comment: If you’re using type applications, you can also write `h = f . g @_ @b` (or `g @a @b`).