# How do you implement Object-Oriented polymorphism in a functional language?

Tags: oop, functional-programming, polymorphism, duck-typing

Say you have this in an Object-Oriented application:

```
module Talker
  def talk(word)
    puts word
  end
end

module Swimmer
  def swim(distance)
    puts "swimming #{distance}"
  end
end

class Organism
  def initialize
    rise
  end
  
  def rise
    puts "hello world"
  end
end

class Animal extends Organism
  def think(something)
    puts "think #{something}"
  end
end

class Bird extends Animal
  include Talker
end

class Fish extends Animal
  include Swimmer
end

bird = new Bird
fish = new Fish
```

In this, you can call methods which are unique to each:

```
bird.talk("hello")
fish.swim(50)
```

But you can also call methods which are the same:

```
bird.think("fly")
fish.think("swim")
```

If I have a function that takes an animal, I can call the think function:

```
def experience(animal)
  animal.think("one")
  animal.think("two")
  animal.think("one")
end
```

In a pseudo functional language, you can do the same basically:

```
function experience(animal) {
  think(animal)
  think(animal)
  think(animal)
}
```

But not really, you would have to check the type:

```
function think(genericObject) {
  if (genericObject is Animal) {
    animalThink(genericObject)
  } else if (genericObject is SomethingElse) {
    somethingElseThink(genericObject)
  }
}
```

That is because, when implementing your "experience" function, you don't want just animals to experience, you want rocks and trees and other things to experience too, but their experience functions are different.

```
function experience(thing) {
  move(thing)
  move(thing)
  move(thing)
}

function move(thing) {
  case thing {
    match Animal then animalMove(thing)
    match Plant then plantMove(thing)
    match Rock then rockMove(thing)
  }
}
```

In this way, you can't have a cleanly reusable function, *your function must know of the specific types it's going to receive somewhere down the line*.

Is there any way to avoid this and make it more like OO polymorphism, in a functional language?

If so, at a high level, how does it work under the hood if this can be solved in a functional language?

- [Achieving polymorphism in functional programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969593/achieving-polymorphism-in-functional-programming)
- https://www.quora.com/How-is-polymorphism-used-in-functional-programming-languages
- https://wiki.haskell.org/OOP_vs_type_classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functional programming languages have a variety of ways of achieving polymorphism. I'm going to contrast Java (the OOP language I know best) with Haskell (the functional language I know best).

Way 1: "parametric polymorphism"

With parametric polymorphism, you don't need to know anything at all about the underlying type. For example, if I have a singly-linked list with elements of type T, I actually don't need to know anything about type T in order to find the length of the list. I would just write something like

```hs
length :: forall a . [a] -> Integer
length [] = 0
length (x:xs) = 1 + length xs
```

in Haskell (obviously I'd want to use a better algorithm in practice, but you get the idea). Note that it doesn't matter what the type of the list elements is; the code for getting the length is the same. The first line is the "type signature". It says that for every type a, length will take a list of a and output an integer.

This can't be used for too much "serious polymorphism", but it's definitely a strong start. It corresponds roughly to Java's generics.

Way 2: typeclass-style polymorphism

Even something as benign as checking for equality actually requires polymorphism. Different types require different code for checking equality, and for some types (generally functions), checking equality is literally impossible because of the halting problem. Thus, we use "type classes".

Let's say I define a new type with 2 elements, Bob and Larry. In Haskell, this looks like

```hs
data VeggieTalesStars = Bob | Larry
```

I would like to be able to compare two elements of type VeggieTalesStars for equality. To do this, I would need to implement an Eq instance.

```hs
instance Eq VeggieTalesStars where
    Bob == Bob     = True
    Larry == Larry = True
    Bob == Larry   = False
    Larry == Bob   = False
```

Note that the function (==) has the type signature

```hs
(==) :: forall b . Eq b => b -> b -> Bool
```

This means that for every type b, if b has an Eq instance, then (==) can take two arguments of type b and return a Bool.

It's probably not too difficult for you to guess that the not-equals function (/=) also has the type signature

```hs
(/=) :: forall b . Eq b => b -> b -> Bool
```

Because (/=) is defined by

```hs
x /= y = not (x == y)
```

When we call the (/=) function, the function will deploy the correct version of the (==) function based on the types of the arguments. If the arguments have different types, you won't be able to compare them using (/=).

Typeclass-style polymorphism allows you to do the following:

```hs
class Animal b where
    think :: b -> String -> String
    -- we provide the default implementation
    think b string = "think " ++ string

data Fish = Fish
data Bird = Bird

instance Animal Fish where
instance Animal Bird where
```

Both Fish and Bird implement the "Animal" typeclass, so we can call the think function on both. That is,

```hs
>>> think Bird "thought"
"think thought"
>>> think Fish "thought"
"think thought"
```

This use case corresponds roughly to Java interfaces - types can implement as many type classes as they want. But type classes are far more powerful than interfaces.

Way 3: Functions

If your object only has one method, it may as well just be a function. This is a very common way to avoid inheritance hierarchies - deal with functions rather than inheritors of a 1-method base class.

One might therefore define

```hs
type Animal = String -> String
    
basicAnimal :: Animal
basicAnimal thought = "think " ++ thought
```

An "animal" is really just a way of taking one string and producing another. This would correspond to the Java code

```java
class Animal {
    public String think(String thought) {
        return "think " + thought;
    }
}
```

Let's say that in Java, we decided to implement a subclass of animal as follows:

```java
class ThoughtfulPerson extends Animal {
    private final String thought;
    public ThoughtfulPerson(final String thought) {
        this.thought = thought;
    }

    @Override
    public String think(String thought) {
        System.out.println("I normally think " + this.thought ", but I'm currently thinking" + thought + ".");
    }
}
```

In Haskell, we would implement this as

```hs
thoughtfulPerson :: String -> Animal
thoughtfulPerson originalThought newThought = "I normally think " ++ originalThought ", but I'm currently thinking" ++ newThought ++ "."
```

The "dependency injection" of Java code is realised by Haskell's higher-order functions.

Way 4: composition over inheritance + functions

Suppose we have an abstract base class Thing with two methods:

```java
abstract class Thing {
    public abstract String name();
    public abstract void makeLightBlink(int duration);
}
```

I'm using Java-style syntax, but hopefully it's not too confusing.

Fundamentally, the only way to use this abstract base class is by calling its two methods. Therefore, a Thing should actually be considered to *be* an ordered pair consisting of a string and a function.

In a functional language like Haskell, we would write

```hs
data Thing = Thing { name :: String, makeLightsBlink :: Int -> IO () }
```

In other words, a "Thing" consists of two parts: a name, which is a string, and a function makeLightsBlink, which takes an Int and outputs an "IO action". This is Haskell's way of dealing with IO - through the type system.

Instead of defining subclasses of Thing, Haskell would just have you define functions which output a Thing (or define Things themselves directly). So if in Java you might define

```java
class ConcreteThing extends Thing {
    @Override
    public String name() {
        return "ConcreteThing";
    }

    @Override
    public void makeLightsBlink(int duration) {
        for (int i = 0; i < duration; i++) {
            System.out.println("Lights are blinking!");
        }
    }
}
```

In Haskell, you would instead define

```hs
concreteThing :: Thing
concreteThing = Thing { name = "ConcreteThing", makeLightsBlink = blinkFunction } where
    blinkFunction duration = for_ [1..duration] . const $ putStrLn "Lights are blinking!"
```

No need to do anything fancy. You can implement any behaviour you want by using composition and functions.

Way 5 - avoid polymorphism entirely

This corresponds to the "open vs closed principle" in object oriented programming.

Some times, the correct thing to do is actually to avoid polymorphism entirely. For example, consider how one might implement a singly-linked list in Java.

```java
abstract class List<T> {
    public abstract bool is_empty();
    public abstract T head();
    public abstract List<T> tail();

    public int length() {
        return empty() ? 0 : 1 + tail().length();
    }
}

class EmptyList<T> {
    @Override
    public bool is_empty() { 
        return true; 
    }

    @Override
    public T head() { 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("can't take head of empty list"); 
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> tail() { 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("can't take tail of empty list"); 
    }
}

class NonEmptyList<T> {
    private final T head;
    private final List<T> tail;

    public NonEmptyList(T head, List<T> tail) {
        this.head = head;
        this.tail = tail;
    }

    @Override
    public bool is_empty() { 
        return false; 
    }

    @Override
    public T head() { 
        return self.head; 
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> tail() { 
        return self.tail; 
    }
}
```

However, this is actually *not* a good model because you'd like there to only be two ways of constructing a list - the empty way, and the non-empty way. Haskell allows you to do this quite simply. The analogous Haskell code is

```hs
data List t = EmptyList | NonEmptyList t (List t)

empty :: List t -> Bool
empty EmptyList = True
empty (NonEmptyList t listT) = False

head :: List t -> t
head EmptyList = error "can't take head of empty list"
head (NonEmptyList t listT) = t

tail :: List t -> List t
tail EmptyList = error "can't take tail of empty list"
tail (NonEmptyList t listT) = listT

length list = if empty list then 0 else 1 + length (tail list)
```

Of course, in Haskell we try to avoid functions that are "partial" - we try to make sure that every function always returns a value. So you won't see many Haskellers actually using the "head" and "tail" functions for precisely this reason - they sometimes error out. You'd instead see length defined by

```hs
length EmptyList = 0
length (NonEmptyList t listT) = 1 + length listT
```

using pattern-matching.

This feature of functional programming languages is called "algebraic data types". It's incredibly useful.

Hopefully, I've convinced you that not only does functional programming allow you to implement many object-oriented design patterns, it can actually allow you to express the same ideas in much more succinct and obvious forms.

Comment: I like this answer but the Single Responsibility Principle is unrelated to the number of methods in a class. I would leave the SOLID principles out of this, as they are unrelated to the question but add unnecessary complexity to the answer.

Comment: @jaco0646 It's true that "single responsiblity" doesn't *just* mean one method. But it is a related notion.

Comment: A class can have ten methods with one responsibility or one method with ten responsibilities. There is no relation between method count and responsibility count.

Comment: @jaco0646 After careful reflection, I have concluded that you are correct and I was incorrect. I have updated my post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I have added some sugar to your example because it was difficult to justify an object centric implementation with your functions.

Note that I don't write a lot of Haskell but I think it's the right language to draw a comparison.

I don't recommend comparing pure OO languages and pure FP languages directly as it is a waste of time. If you pick up a FP language and learn how to think functionally you will not miss any OO feature.

```hs
-- We define and create data of type Fish and Bird

data Fish = Fish String
nemo = Fish "Nemo";

data Bird = Bird String
tweety = Bird "Tweety"


-- We define how they can be displayed with the function `show`

instance Show Fish where
    show (Fish name) = name ++ " the fish"

instance Show Bird where
    show (Bird name) = name ++ " the bird"


{- We define how animals can think with the function `think`.
   Both Fish and Bird will be Animals.
   Notice how `show` dispatches to the correct implementation.
   We need to add to the type signature the constraint that
   animals are showable in order to use `show`.
-}

class Show a => Animal a where
    think :: a -> String -> String
    think animal thought =
        show animal ++ " is thinking about " ++ thought

instance Animal Fish
instance Animal Bird


-- Same thing for Swimmer, only with Fish

class Show s => Swimmer s where
    swim :: s -> String -> String
    swim swimmer length =
        show swimmer ++ " is swimming " ++ length

instance Swimmer Fish


-- Same thing for Singer, only with Bird

class Show s => Singer s where
    sing :: s -> String
    sing singer = show singer ++ " is singing"

instance Singer Bird


{- We define a function which applies to any animal.
   The compiler can figure out that it takes any type
   of the class Animal because we are using `think`.
-}

goToCollege animal = think animal "quantum physics"


-- we're printing the values to the console

main = do
    -- prints "Nemo the fish is thinking about quantum physics"
    print $ goToCollege nemo

    -- prints "Nemo the fish is swimming 4 meters"
    print $ swim nemo "4 meters"

    -- prints "Tweety the bird is thinking about quantum physics"
    print $ goToCollege tweety

    -- prints "Tweety the bird is singing"
    print $ sing tweety
```

I was wondering what it would look like in Clojure. It's not as satisfying because `defprotocol` doesn't provide default implementations, but then again: are we not forcing a style upon a language which is not designed for it?

```clj
(defprotocol Show
    (show [showable]))

(defprotocol Animal
    (think [animal thought]))

(defn animal-think [animal thought]
    (str (show animal) " is thinking about " thought))

(defprotocol Swimmer
    (swim [swimmer length]))

(defprotocol Singer
    (sing [singer]))

(defrecord Fish [name]
    Show
    (show [fish] (str (:name fish) " the fish"))
    Animal
    (think [a b] (animal-think a b))
    Swimmer
    (swim [swimmer length] (str (show swimmer) " is swimming " length)))

(defrecord Bird [name]
    Show
    (show [fish] (str (:name fish) " the bird"))
    Animal
    (think [a b] (animal-think a b))
    Singer
    (sing [singer] (str (show singer) " is singing")))

(defn goToCollege [animal]
    (think animal "quantum physics"))

(def nemo (Fish. "Nemo"))

(def tweety (Bird. "Tweety"))

(println (goToCollege nemo))
(println (swim nemo "4 meters"))
(println (goToCollege tweety))
(println (sing tweety))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that what kind of polymorphism you want. If you just need some polymorphism on compile time, Haskell's `typeclass` is nearly perfect for most situations.

If you want to have polymorphism of run time(i.e. dynamically switch behaviors based on runtime type), this programming pattern is discouraged in many functional programming languages since with powerful generics and typeclasses, dynamic polymorphism is not always necessary.

In short, If the language support subtype, you can choose dynamic polymorphism while in a strict functional language without complete subtypes, you should always program in a functional way. Lastly, If you still want both(dynamic polymorphism and powerful typeclasses), you can try languages with ***traits*** like `Scala` or `Rust`.